# How to make a dynamic change and access a parent element on a value using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where it is related to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203780/how-to-access-parent-element-and-then-get-its-value-and-then-append-to-other-el). What I want to do is to get the previous value inside my input element labeled "SERIAL END" then automatically appends it's value when adding a row to "SERIAL START", and not only append but will add +1 to it's value (this is solved), but I want to add a function when the value is already added, it will get the value of the edited parent element and can be changeable but still adds the children element's value by +1.

Here is my whole code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addrow").on("click", function() {
    var startElement = $("#start");
    var value = parseInt(startElement.val());
    startElement.val(value);
    var hidden = startElement.val();
    var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl').rows.length;
    if (tbl === 5) {
      alert("It is limited for 5 rows only");
    } else {
      var lasttr = $('#tbl tr:last').attr('id');
      var lastinsertedrow = lasttr.replace('tablerow_', '');

      var end = $('#serend' + lastinsertedrow).val();
      end = (parseInt(end) + parseInt(1));
      var newRow = $("<tr id='tablerow_" + hidden + "'>");
      var cols = "";

      cols +=
        '<td><select onchange="selectmodel(this)"data-live-search="true" placeholder="Select your model name"id="model' +
        hidden + '" class="form-control selectpicker show-menu-arrow " name="model[]" required><option selected disabled> Select your model name</option><?php $sql = mysqli_query($con,"call gettrial");
      if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
          echo "<option value=$row[id]>".$row['model_name'].
          " </option>";
        }
      } ? > < /select></td > ';
      cols +=
        '<td><input id="code' + hidden +
        '" value="" type="text" class="form-control" name="code[]" readonly="" /></td>';
      cols +=
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="serstart' + hidden +
        '" name="serstart[]"  value="' + end + '" readonly/></td>';
      cols +=
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="serend' + hidden +
        '" name="serend[]" onchange="myChangeFunction(this)" required /></td>';
      newRow.append(cols);
      $("table.order-list").append(newRow)
        .find('.selectpicker')
        .selectpicker({
          liveSearch: true,
          showSubtext: true
        });
      $("#serend" + hidden).on("change", function(e) {
        var x = $("#serend").val()
        if ($(this).val() > (x * 100) / 100) {
          alert("You exceed in " + x + " pls do enter below or exact " + x)
        }
      })
      const hide = document.getElementById('start');
      hide.value = (parseInt(hidden) + parseInt(1));
      hidden++;
    }
  });
  $('#remove').click(function() {
    $("#myTable").each(function() {
      if ($('tr', this).length > 2) {
        $('tr:last', this).remove();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php 
include ('../include/header_pis.php');
?>
<html>
<title>Lot_Registration</title>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1 class="page-header"> Lot Registration
            <a href="rbg_table.php">
              <button class="btn btn-success pull-right">
                                <span class="fa  fa-reply"> Back </span>
                            </button>
            </a>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              Model Form
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <form class="className" name="form" id="form" action="lot_registration_model_submit.php" data-toggle="validator" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-sm-3">Lot No.: <font color="red">*</font></label>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" type="text" id="lotno" name="lotno" style="text-transform:uppercase" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-sm-3">Month of: <font color="red">*</font></label>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" type="date" id="monthof" name="monthof" style="text-transform:uppercase" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-sm-3">Serial Start: <font color="red">*</font></label>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" type="text" id="serstart" name="serstart" style="text-transform:uppercase" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-sm-3">Serial End: <font color="red">*</font></label>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" type="text" id="serend" name="serend" style="text-transform:uppercase" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" id="addrow" value="Add Row" disabled />&nbsp;
                    <input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger" id="remove" value="Delete Row">
                    <br>&nbsp;
                    <table width="100%" class="table order-list table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="col-sm-3">
                            <center />Model
                          </th>
                          <th class="col-sm-3">
                            <center />Code
                          </th>
                          <th class="col-sm-3">
                            <center />Serial Start
                          </th>
                          <th class="col-sm-3">
                            <center />Serial End
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody id='tbl'>
                        <tr id="tablerow_0">
                          <td>
                            <select name="model[]" id="model0" class="form-control selectpicker show-menu-arrow" data-live-search="true" title="Select your model name" onchange="selectmodel(this)" required>

                              <?php
                                                    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT model.id,model.model_name,model.code,model.status
                                                    FROM model 
                                                    left join grouped on model.id = grouped.modelandcode
                                                    WHERE cat_id='1' and model.status='1' and grouped.status is null 
                                                    ORDER BY model_name ASC"); 
                                                    $con->next_result();
                                                    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0){
                                                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                                                            echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['model_name']."</option>";
                                                        }
                                                }   ?>
                            </select>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input name="code[]" type="text" id="code0" value="" class="form-control" readonly="" />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="text" name="serstart[]" id="serstart0" class="form-control" readonly />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="text" name="serend[]" id="serend0" class="form-control" onchange="myChangeFunction(this)" required />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <input type="hidden" value="1" id="start" />
                    <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><span
                                                class="fa  fa-check"> &nbsp Submit</span></button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
```

Comment: This is simple in short you just need to get index of `tr` where input is edited and then add one to it and then change next td value using that index :)

Comment: @Swati Hi! :) , okay I should probably try this thanks for answering

Comment: Let , me know if that doesn't work .

Comment: Hi @Swati it did not work :( what I did is I set a variable to get that row.                 
`var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');
 var inputLength = thisRow.find('input[id="serend"]').length;`

Comment: @Swati I tried also `var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');  var inputLength = thisRow.find('input[id="serend"]').val();` but it says undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in comment you just need to get `index` of tr where input has changed and then using that access next tr input and add value there.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("[id*=serend]").on("change", function(e) {
  var x = $("#serend").val()
  if ($(this).val() > (x * 100) / 100) {
    alert("You exceed in " + x + " pls do enter below or exact " + x)
  } else {
    //get index of tr
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1;
    var end = $(this).val(); //get value of input change
    end = (parseInt(end) + parseInt(1));
    $("tbody tr:eq(" + row + ") td:eq(2) input").val(end) //add inside next input

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" class="table order-list table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-sm-3">
        <center />Model
      </th>
      <th class="col-sm-3">
        <center />Code
      </th>
      <th class="col-sm-3">
        <center />Serial Start
      </th>
      <th class="col-sm-3">
        <center />Serial End
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id='tbl'>
    <tr id="tablerow_0">
      <td>
        <select name="model[]" id="model0" class="form-control selectpicker show-menu-arrow" data-live-search="true" title="Select your model name" onchange="selectmodel(this)" required>
          <option selected disabled> Select your model name</option>
          <option value='1'>A</option>
          <option value='2'>A2</option>
          <option value='3'>A3</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input name="code[]" type="text" id="code0" value="M12" class="form-control" readonly="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="serstart[]" id="serstart0" value="1" class="form-control" readonly />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="serend[]" id="serend0" value="11" class="form-control"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tablerow_1">
      <td>
        <select name="model[]" id="model1" class="form-control selectpicker show-menu-arrow" data-live-search="true" title="Select your model name" onchange="selectmodel(this)" required>
          <option selected disabled> Select your model name</option>
          <option value='1'>A</option>
          <option value='2'>A2</option>
          <option value='3'>A3</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input name="code[]" type="text" id="code1" value="M12" class="form-control" readonly="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="serstart[]" id="serstart1" value="1" class="form-control" readonly />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="serend[]" id="serend1" value="" class="form-control"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tablerow_2">
      <td>
        <select name="model[]" id="model2" class="form-control selectpicker show-menu-arrow" data-live-search="true" title="Select your model name" onchange="selectmodel(this)" required>
          <option selected disabled> Select your model name</option>
          <option value='1'>A</option>
          <option value='2'>A2</option>
          <option value='3'>A3</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input name="code[]" type="text" id="code2" value="M12" class="form-control" readonly="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="serstart[]" id="serstart2" value="1" class="form-control" readonly />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="serend[]" id="serend2" value="" class="form-control"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ohhhh~ I did not know the method .index() very well. So index() method access the value? or element? sorry I did not get it very well hehe

Comment: index will give you position of tr inside tbody  . So , if you are accessing first `tr` it will give you `0` then if accessing 2nd tr it will give you `1` and so on. Read [this](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to know more.

Comment: Ohhhh that's why awhile ago when I alerted the value it returns zero, index() method is the answer for it. I learned something new right now, thanks @Swati :)